# Switch between two different XML-files with buttons?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to switch between two different XML-files by pushing two buttons, when pushing the first one i want to load t2.wml and when i push the other one i want to load t1.xml. Everything works if i set "num" to a static value but i want to change the value of num depending on what button i push.

I think i have missed something obvious but i cant find out what and i'm stuck here.

Anyone have any ideas of how to solve this problem? And why isn't my function to change the value of num working? :)

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var language:String;
var num:int;
var xmlData:XML = new XML ();   
var array:Array = ["t2.xml", "t1.xml"];
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader_ul.load(new URLRequest(array[num]));



engBtn0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, engButton);
sweBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sweButton);
engBtn0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fileLoaded);
sweBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fileLoaded);


function engButton (e:Event) {

    language = "eng";
    trace (language);
    trace (num);
    } // end engButton


 function sweButton (e:Event) {

    language = "swe";
    trace (language);
    trace (num);
    } // end sweButton



 function fileLoaded(e:Event)    {

    if (language == "eng"){
            num = 0;
            trace (num);
            xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);
            myText_text.htmlText = xmlData.testeng;

    } else if (language == "swe") {

            num = 1;
            trace (num);
            xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);
            myText_text.htmlText = xmlData.testswe;

    } else {
                    trace ("Error");
            }


  } // end fileLoaded
```

Thanks in advance! Really could use some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var language: String;

var loader_ul: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader_ul.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded)

engBtn0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, engButton);
sweBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sweButton);

function engButton(e: Event) {
    language = "eng";
    loader_ul.load(new URLRequest('t2.xml');
} 

function sweButton(e: Event) {
    language = "swe";
    loader_ul.load(new URLRequest('t1.xml')); 
} 

function fileLoaded(e:Event) {
    var xmlData:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    if(language == "swe"){
        myText_text.htmlText = xmlData.testswe;
    } else if(language == "eng" {
        myText_text.htmlText = xmlData.testeng;
    }
}
```

Basically loading your XML from the button itself and add an `eventListener` to the `loader` so when it is complete it triggers the function `fileLoaded` which puts the loaded xml into the right textfield. (I would change the XML into something more generic than `testswe` or `testeng`.

Hope it helps.

If you want to make it more generic you do something like:

```
engBtn0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
sweBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var xmlfile:String = "";

    switch(e.target.name){
        case 'engBtn0':
            language = 'eng';
            xmlfile = 't2.xml';
            break;
        case 'sweBtn1':
            language = 'swe';
            xmlfile = 't1.xml';
            break;
    }
    loader_ul.load(new URLRequest(xmlfile)); 
}
```

And add more `eventlisteners` and more `case`s to the `switch`;

Comment: Thanks alot, never thought of it that way. Seems to work just fine (had to add a few ")" that were missing. Again, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. And if this solution works for you, would you please be so kind to accept my answer :)

Comment: Done :) If i want to use more than two XML-files, is there any more suitable ways to do this or do i just create more functions that loads the next XML?

Comment: Well, each button needs an `eventListener` but you can asign them all to the same function and check in that function what button you clicked and perform the load to that. See my update in answer.